# css menu items overlaying one another

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I cannot get my drop down menu items to display correctly. Each items in the list (4 of them) appear on top of each other. Any help is greatly appreciated.

this is my html:

```
<nav>

            <ul >
                <li><a href='#'><span>SERVICES</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='../escuela_eng.html'><span>Equest Sch</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href='../hst_eng.html'><span>Horse Assist </span></a></li>
                        <li><a href='../car_eng.html'><span>Care and Recuperation</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href='../ht_eng.html'><span>Training</span></a></li>
                    </ul>

            </ul>
        </nav>
```

and css:

```
nav 
{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0;
    left:-.7em;
}       


nav ul
{
        list-style:none;
}

nav ul li
{
        display:relative;
        float:left;
        padding:0px  15px;
}

nav ul li ul {
    display: none; 
     position:relative;
     top:15px;
     left:0;
}

ul li ul li {
     display:block;
     float:none;
     position:absolute;
     background: #F0EFE7;
     padding:0px 10px;
    }

ul li:hover ul {
     display:block;
     position:relative;
     margin-left:-17px; 
 }


nav ul li a
{
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-UltraLight', cursive;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    transition: all .25s ease;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}

nav ul li a:hover
{
    color:#E56038;
}
```

Many thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'position:absolute' and add 'clear:both; overflow:auto;' to the `ul li ul li`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kc79mwbr/

Comment: thank you gopalarju and @Matt Shade for your time and guidance . Both have helped me understand my (many!) errors. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
  nav 
  {
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0;
    left:-.7em;
  }
  
  
  
  nav ul
  {
    list-style:none;
  }
  
  nav ul li
  {
    /*        display:block;
    */
    /*        float:left;
    */
    padding:0px  15px;
  }
  
  nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
    
    /*     position:relative;
    */
    top:15px;
    left:0;
  }
  
  ul li ul li {
 
    /*     display:block;
    */
    /*     float:left;
    */
    /*     position:relative;
    */
    background: #F0EFE7;
    padding:0px 10px;
  }
  
  ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:-17px;
    
  }
  
  
  nav ul li a
  {
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-UltraLight', cursive;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    transition: all .25s ease;
    /*    position:relative;
    */
    /*    float:left;
    */
  }
  
  nav ul li a:hover
  {
    color:#E56038;
  }
  /*span,a,li{
  display:block;
}*/
</style>

<nav>
  
  <ul >
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        <span>
          SERVICES
        </span>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='../escuela_eng.html'>
            <span>
              Equest Sch
            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='../hst_eng.html'>
            <span>
              Horse Assist 
            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='../car_eng.html'>
            <span>
              Care and Recuperation
            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='../ht_eng.html'>
            <span>
              Training
            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I commented out a lot of the positioning and floating.  I think they were causing problems.  You could put a max-width on the menu if you wish it to be a certain width.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<style>
nav {
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    /*bottom:0;*/
    left:-.7em;
}       


nav ul{
    list-style:none;
}

nav ul li{
    display:relative;
    float:left;
    padding:0px  15px;
}

nav ul li ul {
    display: none; 
    position:relative;
    /*you will need set top margine in such a way that there wont be any blank space between parent menu item and sub menu items*/
    top:15px;
    left:0;
    /*line below will prevent displacement of submenu towards right*/
    padding-left: 0;
}

ul li ul li {
    display:block;
    float:none;
    /*position:absolute;*/
    background: #F0EFE7;
    padding:0px 10px;
    overflow: auto;
    clear: both;
}

ul li:hover ul {
     display:block;
     position:relative;
     /*margin-left:-17px; */
 }


nav ul li a{
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-UltraLight', cursive;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    transition: all .25s ease;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
    color:#E56038;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<nav>

            <ul >
                <li><a href='#'><span>SERVICES</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='../escuela_eng.html'><span>Equest Sch</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href='../hst_eng.html'><span>Horse Assist </span></a></li>
                        <li><a href='../car_eng.html'><span>Care and Recuperation</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href='../ht_eng.html'><span>Training</span></a></li>
                    </ul>

            </ul>
        </nav>                                  
</body>
</html>
```

**You will see following changes**

- `ul li ul li` doesn't need to have `position:absolute` - this was the main reason behind sub-menu items were overlapping each other.
- Only for testing purpose I have commented `nav`'s `bottom:0;`

**Few of the suggestions**

- Please apply classes to `ul`'s and `li`'s
- Manage `padding` and `magines` more efficiently.

**Please refer following links for more info**

- [StackExchange for Submenu CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537270/add-sub-sub-menus-to-a-css-menu-with-sub-menus)
- [CSS-Tricks for Submenu CSS](https://css-tricks.com/targetting-menu-elements-submenus-navigation-bar/)

**Your concerns**

- I have tested this code in Firefox and I can select the menu items.
- Displacement of Sub-menu items has been taken care of in the updated code provided in the answer
- To prevent certain alignment / float issues (with referenced to `Latest Evetns and Contact`) links you will need to test it with FLOAT attributes.

Comment: Many thanks Pralhad Narsinh Sonar. That has gone some way to resolving the problem. The dropdown menu does now however displace the menus to the right (Activities and Latest Events move right and Contact appears on a new line). Is there any way that this could be prevented. Also, the dropdown menus appear with a kind of scrollbar ? can this be avoided ? A third thing is it seems the dropdown menus can no longer be selected. (They dissappear when i scroll down) )Many thanks for you time

Comment: I have updated the answer with addressing your concerns. You may take the directions from the code provided.

Comment: I see them now!  the code provided has changed?  I will try this.Thank you!