# Absolute positioned elements mess up when browser scales

Tags: html, css

I am creating dropdown menu for my website, they look very nice on laptop resolution ( `1280 x 800` ), but unfortunately, they mess up very badly when they are scaled on bigger size, they separate from each other, even though they are absolute.

HTML code of one of dropdown navigation links:

```
<ul class="down-bar" style="list-style:hidden">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <input type="checkbox" value="drop" id="drop-1" class="dropper">
        <li><label class="down-nav" id="down-nav-1" for="drop-1" style="text-decoration:none">Buttons <b class="caret"> &#9660;</b></label></li>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a href="#" class="fix1"><label class="image1" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;top:1%;left:3%;cursor:pointer;"></label>Btn</a>
            <a href="#"><label class="image2" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:3%;top:11%;cursor:pointer;"></label>Btn</a>
            <a href="#"><label class="image3" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:3%;top:21%;cursor:pointer;"></label>Btn</a>
            <a href="#" class="fix2"><label class="image4" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:3%;top:31%;cursor:pointer;"></label>Btn</a>
            <a href="#"><label class="image5" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:3%;top:41%;cursor:pointer;"></label>Btn</a>
            <a href="#" class="fix3"><label class="image6" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:0.7%;top:51%;cursor:pointer;"></label>Btn</a>
            <a href="#"><label class="image7" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:0.7%;top:61%;cursor:pointer;"></label>Btn</a>
            <a href="#" class="fix4"><label class="image8" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:1.5%;top:71%;cursor:pointer;"></label>Btn</a>
            <a href="#" class="fix5"><label class="image9" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:0.7%;top:81%;cursor:pointer;"></label>Btn</a>   
            <a href="#" class="fix6"><label class="image10" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:1%;top:91%;cursor:pointer;"></label>Btn</a>                    
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please note that i didn't add exact original code, for specific purposes.
Class `image(n)` for example `image1`, holds picture next to the text, However `fix(n)` class was for longer texts so it could fit in properly. ( I used text-indent ) for that.

---

[Full Result](https://jsfiddle.net/yek2mrs9/embedded/result/). ( It includes original website buttons, for exact support, try scaling it down and up ).

I think i am making these dropdown menu's wrong, and need to make them with different position types, is that true? if so then what to i need to change?

Comment: your JSFiddle smells like CSGO =)

Comment: What is the problem? It's really hard to understand what is wrong here (what do you get vs what you expect to get?)

Comment: Your dropdown menu should be made with li.
[Here's the complete reference on how to make a menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537270/add-sub-sub-menus-to-a-css-menu-with-sub-menus)

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay it actually is CSGO website :)

Comment: @Dekel the problem is the dropdown menu itself, i think i am making it incorrectly and need answer how to make it more correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fixing it by setting maximum width for the navigation menu container.

```
.down-bar{
  max-width: 1200px; /* try different value */
}
```

The menu item will maintain the same distance on zoom in or out.

Comment: That's a very good idea! i was actually trying to do that on dropdown, Thanks a lot!